# Match column value with substring from reference table in Excel

Tags: excel, substring

I have a reference table on sheet1

```
|       A       |     B    |
|---------------|----------|
|      dog      |    10    |
|---------------|----------|
|      cat      |    20    |
|---------------|----------|
```

I then have a list  with values on sheet 2

```
|       D           |     E    |
|-------------------|----------|
|  wild dog 2       |          |
|-------------------|----------|
| strange cat Willy |          |
|-------------------|----------|
```

I would like E to contain the value of B from the reference table, using the first substring match

I tried with VLOOKUP and INDEX ( MATCH ..) but this is not getting me anywhere. Help or pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current sample data following formula will work. But don't know how is your actual data.

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$10,MATCH(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(D1," ", REPT(" ",100)),100,100)),$A$1:$A$10,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the formula from Harun24HR and simplifying it.

```
=(INDEX($B$1:$B$10;MATCH(1;COUNTIF(D1;"*" & $B$1:$B$10 & "*");0));
```